# Fastest MySQL update of multiple columns on many many single rows

Tags: php, mysql, performance, sql-update

I have a weather data table that has been collecting certain sensor data for years. I now need to add a couple of new sensors (columns) to the data collected, and then fill in the missing sensor data for the past few years. We are talking of about 3 years of 15min records for ~350 stations (~36M records) to update.

This is an example of table, I need to fill in soil temp data:

```
+---------------------+------------+----------+----------+ --- +---------------+---------------+
|       tstamp        | station_id | air_temp | humidity | ... | soil_temp_2in | soil_temp_8in |
+---------------------+------------+----------+----------+ --- +---------------+---------------+
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |     124    |  45.5    |   56.7   | ... |     NULL      |      NULL     | 
+---------------------+------------+----------+----------+ --- +---------------+---------------+
| 2021-01-01 00:15:00 |     124    |  46.3    |   54.5   | ... |     NULL      |      NULL     | 
+---------------------+------------+----------+----------+ --- +---------------+---------------+
| 2021-01-01 00:30:00 |     124    |  45.9    |   55.6   | ... |     NULL      |      NULL     | 
+---------------------+------------+----------+----------+ --- +---------------+---------------+
|        ...          |     ...    |  ...     |   ...    | ... |     ...       |      ...      |
+---------------------+------------+----------+----------+ --- +---------------+---------------+
```

Assuming I will have say a csv file containing al the missing soil temp data, a naive approach would be looping through (e.g. in PHP) each row and run something like

```sql
UPDATE weather_table
SET
    soil_temp_2in = $t_2in,
    soil_temp_8in = $t_8in
WHERE
      tstamp = '$tstamp'
  AND station_id = $station_id;
```

The table has indexes on `tstamp` and `station_id` and the primary key for each record is the combination of those two.

I am quite sure this will take a long while, so I was wondering if there are options to make this update faster.
For instance, here some thoughts:

- is there a way to bulk upload/update the values?
- would dumping the missing data in a temporary table and update the data from there, rather than from csv via PHP, make this any faster? e.g.

  ```sql
  UPDATE table1
  SET column1 = (SELECT expression1 FROM table2 WHERE conditions)
  WHERE conditions;
  ```
- would make the loop in MySQL (cursor? not sure how to do that anyway), instead of PHP, make this faster?
- how about creating/committing a transaction each few thousand records, would that speed things up?
- would adding `LIMIT 1` to the above query make it faster?

I'm not particularly concerned about locking the database for other concurrent queries, I can do this at night or take down the system temporarily while doing this update; I would just make this as fast as possible.

Comment: Can't write up a full answer right now, so do this: use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to load the data into a table then `UPDATE` the `LEFT JOIN` of the two tables to copy the new data into the existing table. No loops required, and just two MySQL statements.

Comment: Unless you want to be able to repeat this several times (in the future, for testing, etc.), I’d skip PHP completely and just do all of this in SQL

Comment: To realize the comments above study **multiple-table** UPDATE syntax carefully. Your naive solution with the subquery in SET clause is not optimal.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` to a new table with the same PK and only the new columns.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, it was exactly what I was looking for!
This is my final solution, which works great (at least on a small test dataset.
I created a temporary `soil_table` and updated my records from there, running the query via PHP in batches of 1 year at a time for each station so I could produce some logs during the process:

```sql
UPDATE weather_table
    LEFT JOIN soil_table ON weather_table.station_id = soil_table.station_id AND
                            weather_table.tstamp = soil_table.tstamp
SET
    weather_table.soil_temp_2     = soil_table.soil_temp_2,
    weather_table.soil_temp_8     = soil_table.soil_temp_8
WHERE
      weather_table.tstamp BETWEEN '$year-01-01 00:00:00' AND '$year-12-31 23:59:59'
  AND weather_table.station_id = {$station_id}
  AND (
    weather_table.soil_temp_2 IS NULL
    OR weather_table.soil_temp_8 IS NULL
  );
```